# django - Restrict "n" or More Characters Present in a Previous Password

Tags: python, django

I am using django for password management and I understand that DJango uses one-way hash to store passwords. My application is using `django.contrib.auth.hashers.PBKDF2PasswordHasher`

I have a table PasswordHistory where I save last 10 passwords. Passwords are saved using django hashing.

I want to restrict user to have a password with "n" or more characters present in a previous password. Right now, it is not possible as I can not get password from hashed string.

Is there a way to do so using django? Otherwise, I will have to save passwords using my own encryption/decryption logic. I know this is not a secure way, but may be the last option I have.

Answer (score 1):

No, this is not possible while using hashed passwords. The whole point of storing hashes is so that you don't store the passwords.

You can prevent *exact* matches with previous passwords, but not approximate/fuzzy matches.

Do not attempt to store passwords in a reversible state, encrypted or otherwise. There is a hall of shame for websites that do this. Encrypting the passwords is *barely* more secure than storing them in plaintext and, really, not secure at all. There's no good reason to do this.